# ngAnimate propagation with angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make little tests with angular. Everything seems working. But i am having problems with the ngAnimate directive.

i build my animation as simply as possible, here is a plunker with my full code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Kg7tkpD4pKMz7eKTOIQS

As you can see, the content is not visible. The class "main_animation" is set but not removed (and why is it set ?)

I use the unstable version of angular but there is no issue about on the official repository.

Can someone help me ?
Thank you.

Comment: if you swap and have "{enter: 'main-leave', leave: 'main-enter'}" - this is the result : http://plnkr.co/edit/KxnmXwst4DN8RC3zZ4Hb - still not sure it s what u want.

Comment: answer was given check it out. my problem never was the animation.

Comment: just for curiosity can u post a plnk where everything work as should?pls thk

Comment: Yep. http://plnkr.co/edit/QPMQ39DzJHKcuo4k5aGZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source of the rendered HTML, you will see without adding the root `div`, `h1` becomes the root div and is assigned with `ng-scope` property. And the title was animated correctly in the original version of your code. In the doc about ngAnimate, it is not clearly said the animation will be applied only on the `DOM` element with `ng-scope` defined, but I think this is the case.

So if you make the template a single root node including all the stuff, the animation will work.

```
<div> 
    <h1>Articles</h1>
        <div data-ng-repeat="article in articles">
            <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
            <div data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="article.content"></div>
        </div>
    <a href="/">Back to home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: a question i hope you have the answer: WHY o.O

Comment: @Nek Updated. Hope it can shed some light on.

Comment: I didn't saw your answer, sorry. Your comment is perfect, thanks.